# How to calculate a function with different equations depending on different ranges?

Tags: python, numpy, function

I am trying to calculate this equation in python.

[image: Equation]

However I seem to be unable to perform the logic operation as had to use array in np to create the decimal range.

I wonder if there is an alternative method of creating the range without np, or an alternative method of perform logic on this.

I would appreciate help on this problem as I am still learning, thank you!

This is what I've tried below.
Although I am getting a syntax error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Did try np.logical_and without success.

```py
# Cardiac Elastance and Compliance Calculation

import numpy as np

# Timestep for one cardiac cycle
# Creates from 0 to 1 spaced by 0.02
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=51)

# Time of ventricular contraction and relaxation
T_vc = 0.25
T_vr = 0.125

#Ventricles 
def vent_elastance(x):
    if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc:
        return 0.5 - 0.5 * cos(pi*x/T_vc)
    #elif x > T_vc and  x <= (T_vc + T_vr):
        #return 0.5 + 0.5 * cos (pi * (x-T_vc) / T_vr )
    #else:
        #return 0

y = vent_elastance(x)
```

Comment: You're missing `:` after `T_vc` in your `if`-condition.

Comment: Also, `x` is not a scalar, so conditions will likely be not that straightforward.

Comment: thanks I missed the colon out while trying different things but get this error now ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You can't use arrays in `if` expressions.  And `if` is a simple branch, that only works with scalar True/False.  `x >= 0` with an array produces a boolean array, multiple values - hence the ambiguity error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function with list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

# Timestep for one cardiac cycle
# Creates from 0 to 1 spaced by 0.02
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=51)
# Time of ventricular contraction and relaxation
T_vc = 0.25
T_vr = 0.125

#Ventricles 
def vent_elastance(x):
    if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc:
        return 0.5 - 0.5 * np.cos(np.pi*x/T_vc)
    
    elif x > T_vc and  x <= (T_vc + T_vr):
        return 0.5 + 0.5 * np.cos(np.pi * (x-T_vc) / T_vr )
    
    else:
        return 0

y = [vent_elastance(_x) for _x in x]
print(y)
```

Outputs:

```
[0.0, 0.015708419435684462, 0.06184665997806821, 0.13551568628929422, 0.23208660251050173, 0.3454915028125263, 0.46860474023534326, 0.5936906572928624, 0.7128896457825363, 0.8187119948743449, 0.9045084971874737, 0.9648882429441257, 0.9960573506572389, 0.9842915805643155, 0.8644843137107056, 0.6545084971874738, 0.4063093427071376, 0.18128800512565496, 0.03511175705587444, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Also, you could just `vectorize` the function:

```
vent_elastance = np.vectorize(vent_elastance)
y = vent_elastance(x)
```

Comment: FWIW, `np.vectorize` doesn't actually give any performance benefit -- it's just syntactic sugar for a regular loop.

Comment: Yes I really like vectorize actually

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi it vectorizes it (enough) for it to work and not raise an error...? That has to count for something. Remove the line and you get: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @Ori I misspoke, and edited my comment to what I meant. Lots of people assume that using `np.vectorize` will somehow modify their function so that it uses numpy's vectorized operations, but that is not the case. See the note in https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Good point! Thanks for the link @Pranav Hosangadi

Answer (score 3):

The equation you've shown says that `e_v` is calculated using a different expression for different values of `x` (or `t` in the screenshot). To do this, you can initialize the result array to an array of zeros (or nans, if you want), and then fill the values corresponding to each group of `x` using the expression for that group. Numpy's vectorized math capabilities make this approach *significantly* faster than the other answers that iterate over the array and calculate each element individually.

```
def vent_elastance(x):
    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    # Create a boolean mask for elements of x that fulfill the first condition
    condition1 = (x >= 0) & (x <= T_vc)
    # Calculate the first expression for values of x that satisfy that condition, 
    # Then set only those values of the result
    result[condition1] = 0.5 * (1 - np.cos(np.pi * x[condition1] / T_vc))

    # Do the same for the second condition
    condition2 = (x > T_vc) & (x <= T_vr + T_vc)
    result[condition2] = 0.5 * (1 + np.cos(np.pi * (x[condition2] - T_vc) / T_vr))

    # Don't need condition3 because it's zero anyway

    return result
```

---

Comparing the runtimes of the different approaches, we see that the vectorized numpy approach clearly beats [Ori's list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75725366/843953) and [user19077881's for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75725350/843953) when the input `x` is larger than ~100 elements. Here, I defined `x` as `np.linspace(0, 1, N)`, where `N` is the input size shown on the x-axis.

[image: Runtime comparison plot]

Comment: Your answer is more efficient but I assumed that it would've been a bit too advanced for OP given OP's question so I gave a simpler answer with list comprehension (and vectorize), which is probably why OP accepted mine.

Comment: \*shrug\* Since they're using numpy already for the `linspace`, they might as well be made aware of its other capabilities. You only learn if you are willing to step outside your comfort zone :)

Comment: No, no, I'm not disagreeing, you have a great answer @ 
Pranav Hosangadi!

Comment: I think these 3 are all really useful answers because not only do they each provide the result, they provide a leaning path and can be compared. I tried to make mine as simple as possible for the OP.

Comment: Ori, I didn't read that as disagreement! Also @user19077881 The "performance" portion of my answer is not meant to put your answers down  in any way -- I just wanted to show how powerful numpy is when it's used the way it's meant to be used. If I thought your answers were bad, I would have downvoted them

Comment: Exactly, which is why the 3 approaches are so useful to compare. I'm maybe surprised that 'full numpy' was not even much faster cf. looping than your timings indicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clear if you are dealing with a List of values or values in sequence. This answer deals with the values one at a time; other answer operate on the whole array at once :

```
# Cardiac Elastance and Compliance Calculation

import numpy as np
import math as m

# Timestep for one cardiac cycle
# Creates from 0 to 1 spaced by 0.02
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=51)

# Time of ventricular contraction and relaxation
T_vc = 0.25
T_vr = 0.125

#Ventricles
def vent_elastance(xlist):
    result = []
    for t in xlist:
        if t >= 0 and t <= T_vc:
             result.append(0.5 - 0.5 * m.cos(m.pi*t/T_vc))
    
        elif t > T_vc and  t <= (T_vc + T_vr):
            result.append(0.5 + 0.5 * m.cos (m.pi * (t-T_vc) / T_vr ))
            
        else:
            result.append(0)
    return result

y = vent_elastance(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you would like to use vent_elastance on each element of x and y will be the vector built out of these elements. On the syntax errors:
instead of `if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc` you need `if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc:` trailing `:` is always required for if statements. `cos` and `pi` are not in python by default, they have to be imported.
My code:

```
# Cardiac Elastance and Compliance Calculation

import numpy as np
from math import cos, pi

# Timestep for one cardiac cycle
# Creates from 0 to 1 spaced by 0.02

x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=51)

# Time of ventricular contraction and relaxation

T_vc = 0.25

T_vr = 0.125


#Ventricles
def vent_elastance(x):
    if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc:
        return 0.5 - 0.5 * cos(pi*x/T_vc)

    elif x > T_vc and  x <= (T_vc + T_vr):
        return 0.5 + 0.5 * cos (pi * (x-T_vc) / T_vr )

    else:
        return 0

y = np.vectorize(vent_elastance)(x)
print(y)
```

output:

```
[0.         0.01570842 0.06184666 0.13551569 0.2320866  0.3454915
 0.46860474 0.59369066 0.71288965 0.81871199 0.9045085  0.96488824
 0.99605735 0.98429158 0.86448431 0.6545085  0.40630934 0.18128801
 0.03511176 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.        ]
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax error is with the 'if' statement.
try `if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc:` and then the code. No, I don't think this is possible outside NumPy, but this is a bit outside my skill set. Judging from the equation, I'd say just use NumPy.

Answer (score -1):

I've also just managed to do it like this, so happy to have learnt all the ways

```
import math

#Timestep for one cardiac cycle
#Creates from 0 to 1 spaced by 0.02

x = [i/100 for i in range(0, 102, 2)]

#Time of ventricular contraction and relaxation

T_vc = 0.25

T_vr = 0.125


#Ventricles 
def vent_elastance(x):

    if x >= 0 and x <= T_vc:
        return 0.5 - 0.5 * math.cos(math.pi*x/T_vc)

    elif x > T_vc and  x <= (T_vc + T_vr):
        return 0.5 + 0.5 * math.cos (math.pi * (x-T_vc) / T_vr )
    
    else:
        return 0

print([vent_elastance(i) for i in x])
```

Comment: [Formatting help](/help/formatting): Add a line that contains three backticks (`\`\`\``) before and after your code to format it as a code block